# How to store 128-d facial encodings in a numpy multidimensional array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, face-recognition

```
image_encodings = np.array(
face_recognition.face_encodings(
bgr_image, self.image_locations, model="cnn"))
self.image_encodings = image_encodings[0]
self.image_encodings_list = np.append(self.image_encodings_list, self.image_encodings)
```

It stores the 128 image encodings as individual rows hence x-axis, I want encodings of one image to be stored as single row, hence 128 columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.image_encodings_list = np.append(self.image_encodings_list, self.image_encodings, axis=0)
```

Comment: It would be good if you would provide some information about why adding `axis=0` is the solution, rather than just the one line of code.

Comment: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/numpy/numpy-add-row-to-matrix/ numpy.append(arr, values, axis=None). The append() function from the numpy module can add elements to the end of the array. By specifying the axis as 0, we can use this function to add rows to a matrix.